# Is it possible to gather the SignatureMethod from the IdP SAML metadata using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 is it possible to gather the Saml2Configuration.SignatureAlgorithm property automatically via the metadata provided by the IdP?

See two examples below, the SignatureMethod is available but it doesn't appear to be referenced in the EntityDescriptor, which focuses on the EntityDescriptor.

Sha1 example
[image: Metadata 1]

Sha256 example
[image: Metadata 2]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The signature algorithm is not exposed in the SMAL 2.0 metadata. You have to ask the IdP.

Comment: Thanks Anders, what is the SignatureMethod in the example for? It's found within EntityDescriptor in the SPs XML.

Comment: The SignatureMethod in the Signature/SignedInfo element defines the hash algorithm used to sign the metadata document. The same algorithm is most often used to both sign SAML 2.0 request/response and metadata. But there is not a direct correlation.